# 16.04: What driver I install for AMD Radeon R7 M260 ?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, 16.04, amd-graphics

I have a Dell with AMD Radeon R7 M260 Graphics card with Ubuntu 14.04.

I have already installed drivers for AMD Radeon R7 M260 in website in AMD.

But If I upgrade my ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, what drivers can I use for keep my performance in my Graphic Cards?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 6 January 2017 the only solution regarding Radeon R7 M260/M265 graphics card with Ubuntu 16.04 in a laptop is to reinstall 14.04. AMD haven't released any updated drivers.

The two open source drivers that support AMD graphic cards in 16.04 - *radeon and amdgpu* - neither work on my laptop. There were no fixes for this issue in 16.04.1 LTS. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is supported till 2019 if that's any consolation. But, yes, it sucks.

Answer (score 1):

The open source radeon driver is used by Ubuntu 16.04 and the fglrx driver is no longer in the repository, the one from the AMD site also will not work since it does not have the capability to support Xorg 1.18.

Fortunately the radeon open source drivers are pretty good since AMD do release the specs for their cards but if you are absolutely set on using the AMD proprietary drivers then you should probably wait and see if they upgrade them to support newer versions of X.

Comment: ok, what drivers do you recommend?

Comment: I use an nvidia card so havn't really had the opportunity to test the latest Radeon drivers but the support for most of the common features seems to be mostly complete you can check the feature matrix on the xorg site and see if there are any dealbreakers for your card before deciding to proceed with the upgrade http://xorg.freedesktop.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/

Comment: "Radeon open source drivers are pertty good" is a bullshit statement.

Comment: printf("Unfortunately %s sucks", "the radeon open source drivers are pretty " );

Answer (score 1):

I mailed the problem to the amd support team and they provided me this link. Haven't tried yet but at least something is better than nothing.
http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx

Comment: I tried it and it made my laptop not start up properly. I had to uninstall driver (using start-up command line) to get back my laptop.