# Ubuntu 14.04 New install ~ No wireless connection properties

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, acer, atheros

I installed 16.04 LTS and got it working, but there were no drivers for my graphics card available as of yet.  Under forum advice, I replaced the 16.04 install with 14.04 and the graphics card works fine now.

The only remaining problem is that there doesn't seem to be an available driver for my wireless network PCI. I can hardwire through ethernet options, but there are no wireless options displayed.
I tried looking through all other similar problems in the forum, tried a few fixes, but none worked. It's even possible that I've corrupted something through my efforts to rectify this in the Terminal.

This is the last fix that I tried:
["Last Terminal codes entered"](https://digitz.org/blog/wifi-issue-on-acer-laptops-running-linux-qualcomm-atheros-device-0042/)
 
**Here is some info from my end:**

```
damian@damo:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 31)  
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e0a1]  
_________________________________  

Manufacturer: Acer  
Product Name: Aspire E5-553G  
Version: V1.08  
Serial Number: NXGEQSA0226370C5947600  
UUID: 84CF8BF7-9122-7A45-8902-54AB3AD3C393  
Wake-up Type: Power Switch  
SKU Number: Aspire E5-553G_109F_1.08  
Family: BR  
_________________________________________________________  

damian@damo:~$ sudo rfkill list all  
[sudo] password for damian:
    0: hci0: Bluetooth  
Soft blocked: no  
Hard blocked: no  
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN  
Soft blocked: no  
Hard blocked: no  
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth  
Soft blocked: no  
Hard blocked: no  
__________________________  

damian@damo:~$ iwconfig  
eth0      no wireless extensions.  
lo        no wireless extensions.  
_____________________________  

damian@damo:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:ab:3a:d3:c3:93  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:473409 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:14427 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:102748527 (102.7 MB)  TX bytes:2626972 (2.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:3439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:458190 (458.1 KB)  TX bytes:458190 (458.1 KB)  
_________________________________  

damian@damo:~$ sudo ifconfigwlan0 up
[sudo] password for damian: 
sudo: ifconfigwlan0: command not found
damian@damo:~$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
damian@damo:~$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
damian@damo:~$
```

***NB***

- I am not running dual boot (formatted drives ~ no Windows) and Ubuntu 14.04 is the only OS on my 128GB SSD & /home is on my 1TB HDD.
- I can connect to the internet via Bluetooth & USB.

Comment: Please post the results of iwconfig and ifconfig -a   Best done with the ethernet cable disconnected since enet will always supercede wifi if both are connected.

Comment: @jones0610   OK. Added requested info into original post (with ethernet cable disconnected)

Comment: Another +1 for a great new user.  This seems to be a popular issue lately.  Your laptop is pretty new so it's possible/likely that your wifi hardware is not supported in 14.04 which is rather old.  So you kind of get to pick your poison.  Might be easier to fix the your graphics problem on 16.04 which is the current LTS release rather than cobble fixes on an old and questionably supported release.  Clearly, this old release isn't seeing your wireless hardware.

Comment: @jones0610 There was no driver available for my graphics card ~ Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265] So it was either 14.04  (nothing higher in version) , until there is a driver offered,  or putting up with jagged & dragging video.

Comment: I found this post regarding your graphics driver: https://askubuntu.com/questions/763906/16-04-what-driver-i-install-for-amd-radeon-r7-m260
Hope it helps...

Comment: @WillemK That was my issue when i installed 16.04 LTS. Thats why I've installed 14.04 until graphic drivers for radeon m260 become available.
Now I can't get wireless options in 14.04 but my graphics is good. It's very frustrating to want to be able to use something other than Win 10, but support seems to be lacking.

Comment: How about installing Ubuntu in VM Player then? That way you even can have both OS's only at the same time.

Comment: OK thanks for all your inputs. 
I couldn't work it out, time-strapped, so I "Live" sessioned a couple of distros and I found Mint 18.1 "Serena" was able to support all my hardware (so far).
I'm not sure of whether Mint is good for what I want, but it seems very user friendly (so far)

Again, thanks for trying to help.